# Rails routing many to one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I thought it's a simple question, but I was just stuck here.

I have two model `Category` and `Project`, and `Category` has many `Project`.

Then, I thought there would be a route like

http://localhost:3000/categories/1872/projects/499, the `1872` will be category' id and `499` will be project's id. The page would display information of the project.

So, I wrote this in `routes.rb`

```
get '/categories/:id/projects/:id', to: 'projects#show', as: 'project'
```

In category's show page, I wrote

```
<% @category.projects.each do |project| %>
<h1>
<%= link_to "#{project.name}", project %>
</h1>
<% end %>
```

But the link I create will be [http://localhost:3000/categories/499/projects/499](http://localhost:3000/categories/1872/projects/499)

### Update

I've changed routes into

```
resources :categories, only: [:index, :show]  do
    resources :projects, only: [:show]
end
```

But, I don't know how to write `link_to` path in category's show page.

I wrote this

```
<% @category.projects.each do |project| %>
    <%= link_to "#{project.name}", category_project_path %>
<% end %>
```

But it threw this error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"projects", :id=>"1982"} missing required keys: [:category_id]
```

Comment: I suggest to read the [Rails Guide about Nested Resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

Comment: Thanks, it's really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Nested Routing for this and I recommend using resources, just write:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :projects
end
```

You can read more here [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

UPDATED:

To correctly link that route, you need to use just the project path `<%= link_to "#{project.name}", project_path(project) %>`

or use category_project_path like `<%= link_to "#{project.name}", category_project_path(category, project) %>`

Comment: I'd always recommend you to stick to the resource routes if you intend to use a route for resource. To limit you can always use only and except, e.g. `resources :categories, only: [:show] do #...`

Comment: I agree, you can also use namespaces if you don't have an actual resource. Just for organisation sake

Comment: Thank you guys, but I encounter a new problem. I've updated my question.

Comment: Thanks again, you've been a great help!

Answer (score 2):

As per your requirement in given scenario 
you have to pass category_id and project_id with path.
Please try this.

```
 <% @category.projects.each do |project| %>
   <%= link_to "#{project.name}", category_project_path(@category, project) %>
 <% end %>
```

I hope it would help you.